# Location Aware Proxy Application

Tags: macos, proxy, networking, location

Anyone know application like network location(mac) for linux,windows.If not i am thinking of developing one for windows or linux.Application knows the location of user home,office etc.. then configure proxy according to the location its a handy tool actually.Any idea how to start that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max I can tell you is the city using the IP address using IP to Geo service. Finding out the exact position like office,home,restroom,metro etc looks quite tough unless you have some GPS device fitted to your computer.

Google launched it's Latitude service, but it was restricted to mobile devices. I am still unable to find how it can be done without any human intervention.

After thinking randomly and crazily, all I can say it that you need to hand over the information beforehand to the application which it can use to distinguish between home office or any other place.

BTW many applications have **"Auto Detect Proxy"** feature built in them. What is exactly you want to do now in this case?

Comment: exact thing here people using proxy at office but not using at home or any other public place.(at least i am doing it).it is very boring job to switch on proxy at work and switch off other places not using proxy.Application here should aware of home,office,or any other and decide using proxy or not.(or which place using which proxy settings)

Comment: Usually operating systems like Linux with their DE's like GNOME have global proxy settings where you need to set the proxy only once and the applications can get it from them.

I don't have any such idea with Windows. Does it exist. This can be a good way since if you use 5 applications, then switching proxy to non-poxy for all applications everyday 2 times would be a tough job.

Now the problems probably boils down to the Operating system. I am not sure of Windows. GNOME and KDE provide such support. I do use such in GNOME